# Eclipse Run Configuration to kill python.exe?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-juno, kill-process, taskkill, run-configuration

I am running a Django server from my run configuration which translates to:

```
python manage.py runserver --noreload
```

The stop button in the error panel doesn't kill the process, so I usually run

> [**pskill**](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896683) python

**How do I add this to my Eclipse run configurations?**

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to create a python file named "pskill.py" containing:

```py
from subprocess import call
from sys import argv

if __name__=='__main__':
    call(['pskill', argv[1]])
```

And add it under "Python Run" in Run Configurations.